# form is not saving changes in dialog modal (popup) Django

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-4, dialog, popup

I’m really new in Django.
I’m trying to implement Modal dialog using forms. The problem is that even when I make some changes in my form, this changes are not shown in database… I have no idea why. When I test form outside Modal dialog, form is working…
Here is my form.py:

```
class anomalie_location_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Anomalie
        fields = ['localization', ]
```

here is my view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def fix_anomalie_stock(request, pk, type_anomalie):

    anomalie_pk = Anomalie.objects.get(id=pk)

    # form to change anomalie position
    form_location = anomalie_location_form(instance=anomalie_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('printinng anomalie_location_form POST ', request.POST)
        form_location = anomalie_location_form(
            request.POST, instance=anomalie_pk)
        if form_location.is_valid():
            form_location.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'anomalie_pk': anomalie_pk,
                'form_location': form_location}

    return render(request, "anomalie/fix_anomalie_stock.html", context)
```

and my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>{{product.product_name }}</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{form_location}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Treter" data-dismiss="modal">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the model.py

```
class Anomalie (models.Model):
    ANOMALIE = (
        ("Etiquette absente", "Etiquette absente"),
        ("Etiquette decalee", "Etiquette decalee"),
        ("Etiquette inconnue", "Etiquette inconnue"),
    )

    ANOMALIE_STATE = (
        ("traité", "traité"),
        ("mise à jour", "mise à jour"),
        ("signalé", "signalé"),


    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE, null=False)
    date_report = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)

  
    localization = models.TextField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE_STATE, null=False)
  
    aisle = models.ForeignKey(Aisle, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   

    def datepublished(self):
        return self.date_report.strftime('%B %d %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

and this is the url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
    path('consult/<str:pk>/', consult_anomalie, name="consult_anomalie"),
    path('fix_anomalie_stock/<str:pk>/<str:type_anomalie>',
         fix_anomalie_stock, name="fix_anomalie_stock"),
   
]
```

So the question is why form is working outside of Dialog Modal ?

Comment: This looks OK. So what happens if you put `{{form_location.errors}}` in the modal header?

Comment: Hi @Melvyn thanks for your answer. I just did it and nothing happened. I mean it appears nothing.

Comment: So you have the same view? If you simply take the form code out of the modal into the main document, then it works?

Comment: @Melvyn exactly. I don't know why it is working outside the modal.

Comment: Can you add the model and urls.py so we have a working example? I can't reproduce this at all, if I fill in the blanks for the missing information.

Comment: @Melvyn I just edit the question :) .

Comment: I see that the view has 2 additional parameters (other than request), but your form action doesn't have url and the additional parameters. Maybe, you need to pass anomaly_type and update the form action to action="{% url 'fix_anomalie_stock' anomalie_pk anomalie_type %}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is simple.

That is, the form in the modal have a submit button. This button has the bootstrap modal `data-dismiss` attribute which makes the modal to dismiss and not the form to submit.

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Treter" data-dismiss="modal">
```

**Remove the bootstrap `data-dismiss` attribute from submit button.**

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Treter">
```

---

**Code snippet in action**

Run the code snippet to see it in action. I've added the modal code from the question. Form `submit()` to alert the form data and `'hidden.bs.modal'` to alert when modal closes. For demo purpose, form has two submit buttons. One with the `data-dismiss` attribute and the other without. You can see that the button (2) alerts the data while the other closes the modal

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Launch modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h4>Product Name</h4>
          </div>
          <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" name="product" class="form-control">
                  (1) submit button with data-dismiss attribute<br>
                  (2) submit button without data-dismiss attribute
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="(1) Treter" data-dismiss="modal"> | <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="(2) Treter">
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('start');
    $('form').submit(function() {
      alert($(this).serialize());
    })

    $('#myModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      alert('modal closes');
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This looks plausible. Please accept answer if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I just applied your code and it worked :D . Thanks so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some details but forms often don't submit properly when inputs are not named. Even your select elements need name and value pair parameters. Have you double checked this?

What can happen with bootstrap is that the modal can confuse the form action. You have it now set to = "". Try removing the action parameter and give your form a unique id.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Also try checking if submit button was posted rather than just the request method.

Comment: `{{form_location}}` equals `anomalie_location_form().as_p()`, meaning Django takes care of rendering, including proper names on form controls.

Answer (score -1):

Modal should be inside the form tag and not the other way around.

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>{{product.product_name }}</h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{form_location}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Nope. Bad guess. Form isn't part of the content flow, can be anywhere in theory.

Comment: have you tried ? because when I did , this indeed was the reason. I suggest you try my solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the question code? What's the difference with yours aside from whitespace? Both wrap modal body and footer inside form. And I have plenty of templates like that, wrapping both the entire modal and parts of the modal, even inside the modal body. What you changed is exactly what the top answer did: you moved data-dismiss from the submit button to a different button.

Comment: sorry , my mistake. , I pasted incomplete code. the entire modal needs to be inside the form tag. I have pasted the entire code in the answer. hope that helps.

Comment: Now put `data-dismiss="modal"` back on the submit button and test if it still works.

Comment: you are right, it does not work if data-dismiss="modal" is on submit button. But you still need modal inside the form tag.